# Scala-GWT status

Tags: scala, gwt, playframework-2.0

Does anybody know the **current status of Scala-GWT** project?

Grzegorz Kossakowski, who was the main author there, seemed to quit the project to work on scalac in the Spring.

However, in an [interview](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/11/scala-gwt) in November 2011, he said

> I expect the next release to be 0.1 and only then I'll be actively
>   encouraging people to try it for real projects. This release should
>   happen in a few weeks (before Christmas for sure).

Scala-GWT is a very promising project, in my opinion, since it complements Play2 for Scala -
Play being the framework of choice when creating applications with a lightweight, stateless architecture and Scala-GWT the framework for rich client applications.

Comment: Look at Vaadin, it uses GWT and Scala.

Comment: Vaadin is a different approach though. It's more like X11 or RDP for the web, except using its own protocol and not supporting any existing apps.

Answer (score 0):

I remember recently having read on the mailing list from a main (and currently the only) developer that he's been away for personal reasons and that he's planning to get back on the project some time soon. But the fact that the project hasn't gotten any funding it its life and the number of developers working on it don't make its future promising. Sadly.

Comment: Actually, the project has received funding from both Google and Typesafe. However, it's true that the project has been chronically under-funded. This is especially unfortunate since the project was so close to being ready to pass its work on to the GWT/Scala teams. It's still possible that volunteers could bring the work to completion, but the required skills are somewhat esoteric.

Comment: From what I understand by watching [this podcast](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/javascript-embedded-dsl-scala) G. Kossakowski is working on [js-scala](http://github.com/js-scala/js-scala)...? (which would be a completely different approach to the Scala-to-JS problem)

Answer (score 0):

[Scala+GWT](http://scalagwt.github.io/)

The Scala+GWT project aims to compile Scala code for the browser via the GWT toolchain.